# Css image slide show having empty white space

Tags: css

I got a css slideshow off the net and installed it , the demo had 8 images in it but i only wanted 3 , so i've have tried this a 100 times to get it working , but i simply can't

I set up a jsfiddle for the initial version - http://jsfiddle.net/jyfcm4jh/ which works perfectly.

And also set one up for the modified version , with only 3 images displaying , but you can see there is a blank space appearing before each image slides to the next

http://jsfiddle.net/jyfcm4jh/1/

Here is my css i edited for only 3 images

```
.css-slideshow img:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation:xfade 15s 10s infinite;
  -moz-animation:xfade 15s 10s infinite;
  -ms-animation:xfade 15s 10s infinite;
  -o-animation:xfade 15s 10s infinite;
  animation:xfade 15s 10s infinite;
}

.css-slideshow img:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation:xfade 15s 5s infinite;
  -moz-animation:xfade 15s 5s infinite;
  -ms-animation:xfade 15s 5s infinite;
  -o-animation:xfade 15s 5s infinite;
  animation:xfade 15s 5s infinite;
}

.css-slideshow img:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation:xfade 15s 0s infinite;
  -moz-animation:xfade 15s 0s infinite;
  -ms-animation:xfade 15s 0s infinite;
  -o-animation:xfade 15s 0s infinite;
  animation:xfade 15s 0s infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from your "xfade" percentages (of `@keyframes`).

Here is how you should choose your values ([from this website](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/#cfimg3)):

> For "n" images You must define:
>
> - a=presentation time for one image
> - b=duration for cross fading
> - Total animation-duration is of course t=(a+b)*n
>
> animation-delay = t/n or = a+b
>
> Percentage for keyframes:
>
> 1. 0%
> 2. a/t*100%
> 3. (a+b)/t*100% = 1/n*100%
> 4. 100%-(b/t*100%)
> 5. 100%

---

**EDIT:**

In your case:

- a = 4s (each color frame appears during 4s)
- b = 1s (the transition lasts 1s)
- t = 15s (you chose 15s for the total duration)

So your percentages in CSS should be something like this (for ***each*** browser equivalent):

```
@-webkit-keyframes xfade {
  0% {
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity:1;
  }

  27% {
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity:1;
  }

  33% {
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity:0;
  }

  93% {
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity:0;
  }

  100% {
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

And finally, you should remove this CSS property (unless you want a white frame effect for each transition):

```
/*
.css-slideshow img:nth-child(1),
.css-slideshow img:nth-child(2),
.css-slideshow img:nth-child(3) {
  -ms-filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  filter:alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity:0;
}
*/
```

You're all set!

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jyfcm4jh/13/)

Comment: thanks, tried that formula and still doesn't work - http://jsfiddle.net/jyfcm4jh/6/   , i set for 4 images

Comment: Try removing the CSS rule I quoted in my edited answer, then it should work.